# Getting SystemForgroundService Leak even I am not using any service in our project

Tags: android, kotlin

```
   197 bytes retained by leaking objects
    Signature: 099e7804c1433b5477fe40e3ebca5ffce0e9dd16
    ┬───
    │ GC Root: System class
    │
    ├─ android.content.res.ResourcesImpl class
    │    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
    │    ↓ static ResourcesImpl.mAppContext
    │                           ~~~~~~~~~~~
    ├─ android.app.ContextImpl instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Retaining 1.5 kB in 11 objects
    │    mOuterContext instance of com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService
    │    ContextImpl.mOuterContext is an instance of com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.
    │    JobInfoSchedulerService
    │    ↓ ContextImpl.mOuterContext
    │                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ╰→ com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService instance
    ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.
    ​     jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService received Service#onDestroy() callback and Service not held by
    ​     ActivityThread)
    ​     Retaining 197 B in 4 objects
    ​     key = b760af12-749b-4001-9fb4-21aa00fd0559
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 5329
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 322
    ​   
    ​     mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
    ====================================
    0 LIBRARY LEAKS
```